# simple update in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

UserTable is:

- id (INT)
- name (STR)
- last_login (DATETIME)

Serving a web page request i have a **user id** in hand and I only wish to update the **last_login** field to 'now'.

It seems to me that there are 2 ways:

1. issue a direct SQL using db_engine (losing the mapper)
2. OR query the user first and then update the object

Both work fine but look quite disgusting in code.

**Is anyone aware of a more elegant way of doing an update-with-no-query using sqlalchemy? Is there another ORM who has got this right?**

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you have a mapper UserTable in place:

```
DBSession.query(UserTable).filter_by(id = user_id).\
    update({"last_login":datetime.datetime.now()}, synchronize_session=False)
```

Additional parameters in the [docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update).

Comment: Actual link to the docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update