# Update Query with SQLAlchemy with condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple update in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017388/simple-update-in-sqlalchemy)

I want to do `UPDATE jobs SET status = 1 WHERE id = 10`. How can I do this with SQLAlchemy. I am using mysql.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html#inserts-and-updates